# react-router base component driven by sub-routes and pages rendered on top of it

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I want to have a `HomeComponent`, that is the main/home view of the app.
It contains a `map` and a detail `div` for the selected map marker.
The items displayed in the map and detail `div` should be driven by routes.

`/cities` should display cities
`/houses` should display houses

In my mind the routes that define what the home view displays are sub-routes of the home view.

```
<Route component={HomeComponent}>
  <Route path="/cities" component=Overview scope="cities">
    <Route path=":id" component=Detail scope="cities"/>
  </Route>
  <Route path="/homes" component=Overview scope="homes">
    <Route path=":id" component=Detail scope="homes"/>
  </Route>
</Route>
```

`scope` is an indicator for the `HomeComponent` which parts of the UI to highlight or render differently. It could probably be extracted from `location.pathName` but that would break, if the routes path ever changes.

So the `HomeComponent` needs to access its child route components `props.items` to know what to render in the map and `detail` div?

Additionally there should be routes that render on top of the home view (using page transitions). The home view should always be present in the DOM at all times, as its expensive to recreate. Where would I put such routes so that there entry/exit can be animated using the `ReactCSSTransitionGroup` component?

The apps homeview should always display either `homes` or `cities` and render any additional routes on top of that. Would I need an intermediate component as a sub component of the Home route to achieve that?

Such additional routes could be:

```
<Route path="/about">
  <Route path="/info">
  <Route path="/contact">
</Route>
```

and they should be rendered on top of HomeComponent (absolute) and can be semi-transparent or have entry or exit animations.

Answer (score 0):

What about giving your HomeComponent a path with a scope variable? You'll need to listen for changes in scope in componentDidUpdate or componentWillReceiveProps to update HomeComponent based on which scope is active. You can pass scope down to child components via props.

If you use this approach, Overview may no longer be needed (as it can be rendered in HomeComponent), but maybe something like:

```
<Route path="/:scope" component={HomeComponent}>
   <Route path="overview" component={Overview} />
   <Route path=":id" component={Detail} />
</Route>
```

If you want the URI for your info/contact pages to be root level, but still render on top of HomeComponent, you can use an absolute path ([react-router docs](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/RouteConfiguration.md#decoupling-the-ui-from-the-url)), something like:

```
<Route path="/:scope" component={HomeComponent}>
   <Route path="overview" component={Overview} />
   <Route path=":id" component={Detail} />
   <Route path="about" component={About}> 
       <Route path="info" component={Info} />
       <Route path="contact" component={Contact} />
   </Route>
</Route>
```

Comment: Did you miss adding the leading slash to make `/about` a global path? Why are you nesting 2 `HomeComponent` routes inside each other?

Comment: I may have misinterpreted the URI need for the about pages. Updated to remove the nesting. About pages can be accessed as /homes/about/info or /cities/about/info. Is that what you're aiming for?

Comment: thanks. I'd rather render about pages above `/:scope` routes whatever. Something similar to the pinterest example of react-router. Where, when you navigate to an about route, the previous `/:scope` is still rendered first. I want to do that for page transitions, the `/:scope` should always be rendered underneath every route.

Comment: I believe my updated suggestion does just that. Have you tried it?